# How to split and copy files from multiple folder in train, test and validation folder

Tags: python, random, shutil

I have a dataset that is composed by 130 folders containing 32 photos each.

From each folder, I want to copy randomly that photos (26 for training, 3 for testing and 3 for validation) to the the respective subfolder (001, 002, 003...) in train, validation and test folder.
So I'll have something like this:

> - Train set
>
>   - 001 (folder contain 26 photo)
>   - 002
>   - 003
>   - ....
> - Validation set
>
>   - 001 (folder contain 3 photos)
>   - 002
>   - 003
>   - ....
> - Train set
>
>   - 001 (folder contain 3 photos)
>   - 002
>   - 003
>   - ....

This is the code:

```
import random
import shutil

n_photo_train = 26
n_photo_validation = 3
n_photo_test = 3

for idx in range(130):

    source = '/Users/john/photodb_original/{d:03d}'.format(d=(idx + 1))
    dest_train = '/Users/john/photodb_sets/Train/{d:03d}'.format(d=(idx + 1))
    dest_validation = '/Users/john/photodb_sets/Validation/{d:03d}'.format(d=(idx + 1))
    dest_test = '/Users/john/photodb_sets/Test/{d:03d}'.format(d=(idx + 1))

    files = random.choice(os.listdir(source))
    photo_train = files[:n_photo_train]
    photo_test = files[26:29]
    photo_val = files[29:]

    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, photo_train), dest_train)
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, photo_val), dest_validation)
    shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, photo_test), dest_test)
```

I get this error: `IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/Users/john/photodb_original/001/'`.

Did I use wrongly shutil.copyfile? Otherwise is there a way to write the code in a more compact and clear way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.choice(os.listdir(source))` will only return a [single element](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) - when you try to index this string you will get an empty string, and the `os.path.join` will return the directory path - which causes your exception.

From your code it looks like you were aiming to use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle). Note that if you are using the shuffle, it mutates the list so your code should be split to two commands:

```
files = os.listdir(source)
random.shuffle(files)
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i have another issue. I get this error `TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'list'` while running `shutil.copyfile(os.path.join(source, photo_train), dest_train)`

Comment: Well, the index slice command used: `files[:n_photo_train]` will return an iterable. and copyfile accepts a single file, you probably want to iterate and copy the file using a comprehension:
`[shutil.copyfile(file, dest_train) for file in os.path.join(source, photo_train)]`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to create directories to copy files inside them or when you have an exception about missing directory try to create it first and then try to copy file again. Anyway here is an example code i think that does what you are looking for.

```
import os
from random import shuffle
from shutil import copyfile, rmtree

org = os.path.realpath('org')
trn = os.path.realpath('trn')
tst = os.path.realpath('tst')
val = os.path.realpath('val')
# How split will be performed 26 3 3
rnd = [trn]*26+[tst]*3+[val]*3

rmtree(trn)
rmtree(tst)
rmtree(val)
rmtree(org)

# CREATE DUMMY DATA
for i in range(1, 131):
    d = os.path.join(org, "{:03d}".format(i))
    os.makedirs(d, exist_ok=True)
    for f in range(1, 33):
        f = os.path.join(d, "{:02d}".format(f))
        open(f, 'a').close()

# ACTUAL STUFF
for d in os.listdir(org):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(trn, d))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(tst, d))
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(val, d))
    files = os.listdir(os.path.join(org,d))
    shuffle(rnd)
    for f, trg in zip(os.listdir(os.path.join(org,d)),rnd):
        scr = os.path.join(org,d,f)
        dst = os.path.join(trg,d,f)
        copyfile(scr,dst)
```

Comment: thanks! I forgot to post that part of code but I have already created the folders 001, 002. in the training, test and validation folders. I don't understand what you've done in "# how split will be performed" section".

Comment: It creates a list of target directory paths.
Basically 26 item for training, 3 item for test, 3 item for validation.
while looping each directory containing 32 picture, you shuffle the list to decide with item belongs to test, validation and training set.